How do I interpret this ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter notebooks? I made sure pandas is installed
I'm using my MacBook and I'm new to Jupyter Notebooks so my apologies if this is a simple fix; basically I don't know too much about how to read/resolve this error. The "requirement already satisfied" line makes me think I already have pandas "somewhere" else on my machine, but I'm not skilled enough yet to know how to proceed from here. Any help/pointers would be appreciated! :) 

Did you restart the kernel?

Also, please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Try restarting the kernel, if this didn't work. do the pip install in the terminal, then restart the kernel.

It says "Defaultinig to " and something about not being able to write there right at the start after %pip install. That is telling you things aren't quite right about what you are doing and so things after that may be not as you think. I'm guessing you have Anaconda/conda involved and should be using that to manage your environment? Maybe? (Note I could have copied and pasted the notification text if you had pasted the traceback as you are supposed to as text. Screenshots, especially alone, are very discouraged as was of sharing things here.)
